# Changing wordpress domain url

Tags: domain, wordpress

I mistakenly changed the wordpress url (domain name) wrong domain name in the admin panel under settings. Now I am not able to access the site/admin panel. It is redirecting me to the new domain name I placed but since it is not registered so I am not able to access.

Is there any option available to revert the changes back to original.

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try giving this a read: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL
I was told to never change those links so I don't have experience with it myself.

Comment: Try contacting the service provider?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the "wordpress url" under "General Settings", then indeed you're in trouble. Don't look into any wp files in your ftp server because that's not where it's stored. This feild is stored in your wordpress database and you need to change that using *phpMyAdmin*. Here's how

1. Go to Cpanel
2. Open phpMyAdmin and access your blog's database
3. Open the table named "wp_options"
4. Change the **value** of the option name **siteurl** to your original address